# ClassCastException:MainActivity cannot be cast to Interface(NetworkCallback)

Tags: android, classcastexception

My app crashed while trying to call RegisterApi and LoginApi classes.

```
btnDismiss.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener(){

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Boolean isVerify = verify();
            if (isVerify == true) {
                checkConn();
                if ((isInternetPresent)) {
                    if (status == 1) {
                        if (rb_01.isChecked()) {
                            RegisterApi api=new RegisterApi(context,(NetworkCallback) context);
                            api.processRegister("android","12345",et_name.getText().toString(),
                                    et_email.getText().toString(),et_mob.getText().toString(),et_pass.getText().toString());
                            Utility.HideSoftKeyboard(activity);
                        } else {
                            showBlueAlert("Please accept the Terms And Conditions");
                        }

                    } else if (status == 0) {
                        LoginApi api=new LoginApi(context, (NetworkCallback) context);
                        api.processLogin("android","12345",et_email.getText().toString(),et_pass.getText().toString());
                        Utility.HideSoftKeyboard(activity);
                    }
                }
            }
        }});
```

**Logcat**

> 10-15 12:47:23.433 32762-32762/com.shopping.faantush D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
>   10-15 12:47:23.436 32762-32762/com.shopping.faantush E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                                                                          Process: com.shopping.faantush, PID: 32762
>                                                                          java.lang.ClassCastException: com.shopping.faantush.MainActivity cannot be cast to com.shopping.faantush.callback.NetworkCallback
>                                                                              at com.shopping.faantush.slidingmenuactivity.LoginPopUp$5.onClick(LoginPopUp.java:250)
>                                                                              at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5280)
>                                                                              at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21239)
>                                                                              at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
>                                                                              at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
>                                                                              at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:234)
>                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5526)
>                                                                              at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                                                                              at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
>                                                                              at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)

Please help me to solve this problem...thank you..

Comment: You miss the fundamentals, I guess. How would you transform an apple into a banana?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should implement NetworkCallback in MainActivity or pass reference as anonymous class.

Pass reference as anonymous class

```
RegisterApi api=new RegisterApi(context,new NetworkCallback(){

//override your callback methods here

});
```

Same for Login API

```
 LoginApi api=new LoginApi(context, new NetworkCallback(){

//override your callback methods here

});
```

Answer (score 1):

if you want to communicate between fragment and activity you have to make sure its parent activity must implement interface which you have created in Fragment.

reference example :http://simpledeveloper.com/how-to-communicate-between-fragments-and-activities/